# Cannot create virtualenv -- bad python path?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, anaconda

After screwing around with packages trying to get django 1.5.1 to run on my laptop, I seem to have really screwed up something with how python / pip is installed on my laptop.  I have Anaconda installed on my system.

I am unable to create virtual environments presently.  When I run `virtualenv ./temp-env/`, I get the following errors:

```
black-rainbows:website User$ virtualenv ./temp-env/

New python executable in ./temp-env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /Users/User/Drop.../temp-env/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/User/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>

  File "/Users/User/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/log.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/Users/User/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/backwardcompat/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>

  File "/Users/User/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/Users/User/anaconda/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 71, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/Users/User/anaconda/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/User/Dropbox/django/website/temp-env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyInt_AsInt
  Referenced from: /Users/User/Dropbox/django/website/temp-env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/anaconda/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/User/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Users/User/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 992, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/Users/User/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 960, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/Users/User/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 902, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/User/Drop.../temp-env/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

I checked where my python and virtualenv paths were, and they all seem to be in my Anaconda path:

```
black-rainbows:website User$ which virtualenv
/Users/User/anaconda/bin/virtualenv
black-rainbows:website User$ which python
/Users/User/anaconda/bin/python
```

But I can't seem to figure out what the issue is, and google hasn't been particularly helpful.  Any advice?

Comment: Did you try creating a virtualenv in a different directory besides temp-env

Comment: I tried calling it a variety of names (with and without a preceding dot) and it gave me the same error.

Comment: I have this same issue as well :( No idea why...

Answer (score 1):

**which pip** You have checked `which python` and `which virtualenv`.  I'd also check `which pip`.  I'm almost certain that it will be the in the same location as python but I'd check (**hint: do `hash -r` if it might have recently changed).

**conda environments** conda has it's own setup for virtual environments.  There are warning messages you might have buzzed past that warn that mixing and matching [conda environment](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/commands/conda-create.html)s and virtualenv environments is a risky business.  Two systems preforming the same magic is likely to end badly (if not today they later when one upgrades).  You might just be looking for :

```
conda create -n new_django python django
```